# Mountain Lion Server Certificates Expiry Renewal

Tags: keychain, osx-server

I have some certificates expiring within a month.  They don't show up in the Server App, but I'm getting emails that they are expiring all the same.  They show up in Keychain Access.

```
com.apple.servermgrd.apns.mgmt
com.apple.servermgrd.apns.mail
Server Fallback SSL Certificate
```

How can I renew these?  Upon right-click on the second cert, I have these options:

[image: right-click]

How can I get this back working with proper certificates?

Comment: I’m curious…you still have an ML server in production?

Comment: Yes. It is still being used.  Apple doesn't offer any mail servers anymore.

Comment: It’s been a long, long time since I’ve dealt with certs on an Apple server so I hesitate to answer especially since I don’t have a machine to test with.  I shudder to think of the security vulnerabilities an okder system like that has

Comment: Well I do apologize.